# Variable precedence not working as intended in downstream GitLab project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using GitLab prime where I have come across this issue trying to override variables in a multi project pipeline setup.

So here's is the problem statement.

I have a pipeline schedule for first project and one of the job of this pipeline triggers pipeline of the other project.
I have variables defined pretty much all across the places like project, group, local etc.
Now, in the schedule, I want to pass some specific variable-value pair and want all the variables having same name in upstream as well as the downstream projects to be overridden by these variable-value pairs that I'm passing in the pipeline schedule.
What i realised after few scheduled runs is that variables of the upstream projects are being overridden while all the variables in the downstream project remain intact.
By what i see in official GitLab doc, variables declared in the schedule have higher precedence than all sorts of variables we use in GitLab.

Can somebody help me with it?

Comment: Please add input/output values in visualized way, its hard to understand problem from text, include as well all jobs/pipelines that are running (full process with example)